# Using Infinispan for hibernate L2 Cache with Spring & Tomcat

Tags: spring, hibernate, tomcat, infinispan, cpu-cache

Has anybody successfully setup infinispan as L2 Cache in spring?

I want to avoid using XA for my datasource. Currently I'm using LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean with JPATransactionManager.

Any tips on setting up the JTATransactionManager that Infinispan requires?

I currently have the folowing for my Transaction Manager:
Notice, that you need to pass the entityManagerFactory to the Transaction Manager.
So the entity manager needs to be fully created in order to crate the TransactionManager.
But if Infinispan requires the TransactionManager, won't this create a circular dependency?

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true"/>
<!-- Transaction Manager -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
  <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
<tx:advice id="txAdvice"/>
```

Update: I'm using bitronix and things seems to be working but I see several warnings:

1) At startup from Infinispan:

STDOUT [WARN ] [2012.02.20 14:29:00] statetransfer.BaseStateTransferManagerImpl - ISPN000159: Unblocking transactions failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to unblock write commands for cache view 1 but they were not blocked
    at org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferLockImpl.unblockNewTransactions(StateTransferLockImpl.java:260)
    at org.infinispan.statetransfer.BaseStateTransferManagerImpl.postInstallView(BaseStateTransferManagerImpl.java:351)
    at org.infinispan.cacheviews.CacheViewsManagerImpl.handleCommitView(CacheViewsManagerImpl.java:520)
    at org.infinispan.cacheviews.CacheViewsManagerImpl.clusterCommitView(CacheViewsManagerImpl.java:387)
    at org.infinispan.cacheviews.CacheViewsManagerImpl.clusterInstallView(CacheViewsManagerImpl.java:271)
    at org.infinispan.cacheviews.CacheViewsManagerImpl$ViewInstallationTask.call(CacheViewsManagerImpl.java:876)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)

2) When running a write transaction:

```
STDOUT [WARN ] [2012.02.20 13:54:14] tm.BitronixTransaction - Synchronization.afterCompletion() call failed for org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization@67c61e31
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextEntry(LinkedHashMap.java:373)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$KeyIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:384)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.SynchronizationRegistryImpl.notifySynchronizationsAfterTransactionCompletion(SynchronizationRegistryImpl.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionCoordinatorImpl.sendAfterTransactionCompletionNotifications(TransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:333)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionCoordinatorImpl.afterTransaction(TransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.afterCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization.afterCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:61)
    at bitronix.tm.BitronixTransaction.fireAfterCompletionEvent(BitronixTransaction.java:497)
    at bitronix.tm.BitronixTransaction.commit(BitronixTransaction.java:244)
    at bitronix.tm.BitronixTransactionManager.commit(BitronixTransactionManager.java:120)
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1010)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
    at com.mckesson.dex.ui.administration.users.SiteUserResourceProvider$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$edc43389.save(<generated>)
    at com.mckesson.dex.ui.viewer.AdaptableForm.save(AdaptableForm.java:407)
    at com.mckesson.dex.ui.viewer.AdaptableForm.attemptSave(AdaptableForm.java:274)
    at com.mckesson.dex.ui.viewer.AdaptableForm$5.buttonClick(AdaptableForm.java:323)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:512)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:164)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.fireEvent(AbstractComponent.java:1219)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:550)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button.changeVariables(Button.java:217)
    at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.changeVariables(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:1451)
    at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.handleVariableBurst(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:1399)
    at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.handleVariables(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:1318)
    at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.doHandleUidlRequest(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:763)
    at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.CommunicationManager.handleUidlRequest(CommunicationManager.java:296)
    at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.service(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:501)
    at com.mckesson.dex.servlet.DexApplicationServlet.service(DexApplicationServlet.java:60)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1359)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at com.mckesson.dex.security.filter.IpAddressAuditFilter.doFilterInternal(IpAddressAuditFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at com.mckesson.dex.security.DexConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(DexConcurrentSessionFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1330)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:484)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:517)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:970)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:904)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:1071)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:823)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:529)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:
```

Comment: I found this config. I'm going to see if I can get it working using this. However, I am currently setup to use 3 different dbs (dev, tests, prod) = (postgres, h2, oracle).  

I build the datasource in the context config and register via jndi. So I'll have to play around a little to see how doable that is using this configuration.

https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search/blob/master/hibernate-search-integrationtest/src/test/resources/beans.xml

Comment: That sounds like a good source for configuring Infinispan as 2LC, but you're most likely gonna need a different hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class, one that points to a JTA transaction manager. It's weird that you need to pass an entity manager to a transaction manager. The transaction manager should be pretty much standalone and JPA should somehow depend on it.

Comment: Re: IllegalStateException in state transfer - what Infinispan version are you using?

Comment: Re: ConcurrentModificationException - maybe you wanna use a different transaction manager, such as JBoss Transactions?

Answer (score 0):

The IllegalStateException has been fixed in Infinispan 5.1.2.FINAL (issue https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ISPN-1882).